# Issue with filtering data from instances

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am having an issue finding the right answer for this.

I have an instance of TobaccoModel and example is provided below.

```
const BrandFlavorData = [
          new TobaccoModel(264, "dleaf", "Example", "Banana", "fruity", "Example description #1", "low"),
          new TobaccoModel(265, "dleaf", "Example #2", "Berry", "berry-ice", "Example description #2", "low"),
          new TobaccoModel(266, "dleaf", "Example #3", "Cola", "fruity-spice", "Example description #3", "low") 
]
```

And I have the below function (part of it)

```
const exampleFunction = () => {
        let filteredData = BrandFlavorData.filter((item) => {
                  let meetsTypeCriteria = type.some(element => item.flavorTypeCategory.includes(element) && !item.flavorTypeCategory.includes(type.join('-')))
    return meetsTypeCriteria
}
```

The issue that I am having is when for example an user chooses a type of "fruity" the meetTypeCriteria pulls "fruity" and also "fruity-spice" and I want to make sure that it only pulls what the user chose.

Below is also my useState that I have for the "type"

```
const [type, setType] = React.useState([]);
```

Here is also my class for the TobaccoModel

```
class TobaccoModel {
    constructor(id, category, brandName, flavor, flavorTypeCategory, description, nicotine) {
      this.id = id,
      this.category = category,
      this.brandName = brandName,
      this.flavor = flavor,
      this.flavorTypeCategory = flavorTypeCategory,
      this.description = description
      this.nicotine = nicotine
    }
}

export default TobaccoModel;
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `item.flavorTypeCategory === element` ?

Comment: Wow I knew it was something simple, thank you Andy!!